# Can I pass commands to "Run window" from Windows Command Prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, vim, microsoft-onenote

According to [this post](https://superuser.com/a/807175/361600), Command Prompt takes the following command and will open a "Run window"

- `explorer.exe Shell:::{2559a1f3-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}`
- The "Run window":

  [image]

How to further pass a command to the "Run window"? I would like to run a local link for OneNote, as seen in [this post](https://superuser.com/a/653555/361600).

---

In particular, for links as below (taken from the example post), it executes well in the "Run window", but cannot be executed properly through Command Prompt.

```
onenote:https://d.docs.live.net/dc516d79ac0/OneNote/@Home/General.one#Verizon%20Bill%20Figures&section-id={4DEE-95E4}&page-id={003E-4B84}&object-id={0DCF-1D9C}&15
```

I think I am missing some simple commands that are available either through Command Prompt or Power Shell. I prefer Command Prompt argument/solution as Gvim on Windows runs things through Command Prompt by default.

---

PS: `start` command for Command Prompt does not open the `onenote:https://d.docs.live....` link properly. I set the default app for `onenote:` links as the newer OneNote app. While passing the full link to the "Run window" opens the desired page in OneNote, prefixing the link with `onenote:` and passing to Command Prompt only opened the OneNote app but does not jump to the desired page.

---

At the end of the day, I am drafting some Vim script to recognize `onenote:` links and open them through the [Vimwiki](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/) plug-in. Will be reporting the full solution in [this thread on Github](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/issues/818#issue-559253596).

Comment: Why must you use the run box?  I'm pretty sure you can do the exact same things with a cmd shell.

Comment: Type `start /?`. `Start "" "onenote:https://d.docs.live.net/dc516d79ac0/OneNote/@Home/General.one#Verizon%20Bill%20Figures&section-id={4DEE-95E4}&page-id={003E-4B84}&object-id={0DCF-1D9C}&15"`

Comment: Thanks a lot! `start "" "onenote:https://d.docs.live.net/.....` works in Command Prompt! I ended up implementing the exact argument in Vim, in [this post](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/issues/818#issue-559253596).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @[Mark](https://superuser.com/users/1118244/mark), one can put whatever that is "runnable" in the "Run window" into Command Prompt, following syntax: `start "" "SOMETHING"`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in powershell.  Its a one-liner using the start-process method:

start-process onenote:"https://d.docs.live.net/dc516d79ac0/OneNote/@Home/General.one#Verizon%20Bill
%20Figures&section-id={4DEE-95E4}&page-id={003E-4B84}&object-id={0DCF-1D9C}&15"

just copy and paste this into a text file, give it a name and the extension .ps1 and run it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Per my use-case, things runnable through Command Prompt is preferred. I noticed that to execute the `onenote:https://` link in Powershell, as you suggested, the link needs to be tweaked carefully. Thank you anyways :)